# Syntax error for parameterized query with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm new to Python (used to C#) and need to use an Access database (.accdb) with it.

The syntax for building SQL Queries is also a bit odd for me.

I have the following:

```
def updateSQL(table,keyField,keyVal,field,newVal):
    sqlCommand = "UPDATE " + table + " SET (?)=(?) WHERE (?)=(?);"
    crsr.execute(sqlCommand, (field, newVal, keyField, keyVal))
    crsr.commit()
    print("Tables update successfully")
```

But for some reason I'm getting the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE
>   statement

I've tried a few different things with the statement and I can't for the life of me work out where it's going wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '?' markers are for *values*, but the column name is not a value.  You never want to put values into your SQL, but you will need put the columns.  Try something like:

```
sql = 'update {} set {}=? where {}=?'.format(table, field, keyField)
cursor.execute(sql, newVal, keyVal)
```

Comment: For protection against "unfortunate" table/column names, `[{}]` would be preferable to plain old `{}`.